# Input value overridden on mutation with v-debounce

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, debouncing, v-debounce

Consider the following example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vdebounce-input-override-ej4nz

It's a simplified (and mostly mocked) version of a larger app, using Observables to get filtered results from multiple APIs, based on user inputs. I need the inputs debounced.
In the app the debounce value is larger, so the issue's less noticeable, but I've lowered it in the example to make the issue easier to spot. I also tried to mock the randomness of the server response times.

The issue is that whenever I get a response back, if I'm typing in the input I lose a few characters, depending on how fast I type.
If I remove the `v-debounce` directive (or the `.lazy` modifier), the issue is gone, but there's no debounce.

I've also raised it on the [v-debounce](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-debounce/issues/4) repo.

<strike>I know I could dump `v-debounce` altogether and use lodash's debounce inside the watch, but I was hoping I don't have to do that (since `v-debounce` is supposed to be catered for Vue, right!?). I've tried to keep things as "Vue" as possible so far</strike>.

---

**Important edit**: (after it was answered) It appears there are two packages defining a `v-debounce` directive. The good one is here: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-debounce), [github](https://github.com/dhershman1/vue-debounce).

```
npm i vue-debounce
```

The one I used is `v-debounce` and overrides the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Understanding the problem

The problem you're having is the interplay between **markup rendering** and **event debouncing** (which may be a problem of v-debounce or an intended behaviour opinions may vary):

- You are debouncing a triggering of the **change event** on the input element

  - That debounced event triggers **with the input's value at the time of call** (that is, it has no memory of call data in the debounced call)
- Separately (at each actual call of the debounce) you have an asynchronous operation (mock server search) change the state of the component, and trigger a **component re-render**

  - This re-render checks the whole of the component DOM, and "corrects" the input value it sees as wrong
- When a debounced change event triggers after an asynchronous operation, it triggers with the **current DOM input value**, which is by now outdated (or even some mangled mess, if you kept typing)

### Possible solutions

The main issue here is that the actual search value should be tracked. You want to **debounce the search action**, not the value change itself (and certainly not the input change events)

#### Handle the debouncing ourselves

[Here is an alternative to your app](https://codesandbox.io/s/debouncing-data-change-reaction-iwtk8), that does the following:

- Keeps a v-model - `search` - no debouncing
- On change of said v-model:

  - If a search is currently underway, **immediately cancels it**
  - Triggers a **debounced search action** (which will only actually start when typing stops)

```
[...]
  mounted() {
    this.debouncedSearch = _.debounce(this.search, 500);
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.$searchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        store.albums = albums.filter(
          album => album.title.indexOf(this.term) > -1
        );
        store.searchTerm = this.term;
        this.loading = false;
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 300));
    }
  },
  watch: {
    term() {
      if (this.$searchTimeout) {
        this.loading = false;
        clearTimeout(this.$searchTimeout);
        delete this.$searchTimeout;
      }
      this.debouncedSearch();
    }
  }
```

#### Debounce directive that doesn't affect `v-model`

[Here is another solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/debouncing-data-change-reaction-ps3eq) that uses a custom directive that debounces an input event handler, **without messing with v-model bindings to `change`**

Here the app:

- Keeps a v-model - `search` - no debouncing

  - On change of said v-model, If a search is currently underway, **immediately cancels it**
- Triggers a **debounced search action** (which will only actually start when typing stops) using a v-debounce directive

```
<input 
  v-model="term" 
  v-debounce="{ delay: 500, handler: search}" 
  @input="clearSearch">
```

Comment: So, basically, `v-debounce` is useless, since it breaks user experience. Thanks for the detailed explanation.